# Azure Logic Apps - MySql Connector for Azure MySql Database that is hosted in Azure

Tags: mysql, database, azure, azure-logic-apps, connector

Hello does anyone know the state of play around the Logic Apps connector for MySql databases hosted in Azure? The (preview) version out there seems to be for on prem connections using a gateway.

Also, does anyone know if it is possible to use the SQL Server connector to connect to a Azure MySQL hosted database?

I need to run a job once a month to extract some data from an Azure MySql hosted database and email it out to a customer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The current mysql connector only supports the connection to the mysql databases hosted on primeses through an on premises datagateway. If you want to access the mysql database hosted on azure, then you will have to write a supplementary azure function to do so.
As for the SQL connector, it connects to the SQL databases only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like a few people are waiting for a connector for My Sql hosted on Azure and have been for a while. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32348629-azure-mysql-connector